# How to change database setting in data-config.xml in SOLR cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am new in SOLR Cloud so sorry for this question. I am using 3 nodes of SOLR and now I need to update database setting in data-config.xml. But I have now idea how to do that. 
In standalone SOLR we have data-config.xml and we can change in it, but I dont how to do this it in SOLR cloud.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data-config.xml is just another piece of a collection's configuration (if it needs it, not all collections have one). So you just get it ready, and then deploy it the same way you deploy schema.xml, by using [bundled utilities](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities):

```
bin\solr upconfig ...
```

Comment: Hi Persimmonium, can you please elaborate this, actually I didn't get you.

Comment: you need to read up on the subject if you are a totally new to the subject https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files